# How to add metadata in each Web Story without plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am trying to write code that can add matadata in head of each web story without any plugin. I have written code that works for WordPress post but not for Web Story.

Please look at the below code and **provide your suggestion** that can help to** add custom metadata in each Web Story** without any plugin.

## PHP Code Here:

function header_metadata_add_to_header() {
if (is_single() || is_page() || 'web-story' === get_post_type() || is_singular('web-story')) {

```
       $current_url = esc_url_raw(add_query_arg(array(), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));

// Check if the current URL matches the pattern
if (preg_match('/^\/web-stories\/(\d+)\/$/', $current_url, $matches)) {
    $post_id = absint($matches[1]); // Extract the post ID from the URL
} elseif (preg_match('/^\?p=(\d+)$/', parse_url($current_url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $matches)) {
    $post_id = absint($matches[1]); // Extract and sanitize the post ID
} else{
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
}
    
    $keywords = get_post_meta($post_id, '_header_metadata_keywords', true);
    
    echo '<meta name="keywords" content="' . esc_attr($keywords) . '">';
    
}
```

}
add_action('wp_head', 'header_metadata_add_to_header');

**You can verify the post metadata here : [Advgyan](https://www.advgyan.com/)**

I am trying to write code that can add matadata in head of each web story without any plugin. I have written code that works for WordPress post but not for Web Story.

Please look at the below code and **provide your suggestion** that can help to** add custom metadata in each Web Story** without any plugin.

**You can verify the post metadata here : [Advgyan](https://www.advgyan.com/)**